# How to get option list from database and select it?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want a dynamic option list which reads from database table lets say table of : Students,

It must show to user the list of `student_name` and when it is selected by user it must send `student_id` of that student to the database. For example:

```
Students table :

student_id             student_name 
----------------------------
1                     John
2                      Edward
```

In users option list must be included only John, Edward.. but when user selects John, the option picker must send only student_id('1') to database.

My current code , but is not fetching list from db :S :
yes, this is my code but for some reasons it ain't work :

```
<select  Name='student_id'>
            <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
            <?
                mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db ("mydb");
                $select="student_name";
                if (isset ($select)&&$select!=""){
                $select=$_POST ['student_name'];
            }
            ?>
            <?
                $list=mysql_query("select * from students order by student_name asc");
            while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
                ?>
                    <option value="<? echo $row_list['student_id']; ?>"<? if($row_list['student_name']==$select){ echo "selected!"; } ?>>
                                         <?echo $row_list['student_name'];?>
                    </option>
                <?
                }
                ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: check the post, i posted the code there at the moment, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');

$sql="SELECT student_id ,student_name  FROM students";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
<select name = "student">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['student_name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: is your query working successfully? What error are getting if any?

Comment: first check,is that query returning results successfully?

Comment: oops,it was my mistake,forgot to 'echo' values. Try the edited code now.It should work

Answer (score 0):

may this one help you

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Students");

echo "<select>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<option id=".$row['student_id'].">" . $row['student_name'] . "</option>";   

}

echo "</select>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: where is the html form of this one ?

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch your database from your PHP, then build your list out of it

```
//YOU MUST ADD YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION
mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
mysql_select_db("dbname");

//HERE IS YOUR SQL REQUEST
$SQL_request = "SELECT * FROM `student_table`";
$req = mysql_query($SQL_request) or die(mysql_error().'<br/>'.$SQL_request);

echo '<select name = "students">';

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)){
    echo '<option value="'.$result['student_id'].'">'.$result['student_name'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
?>
```